# How do I change where my highlights get saved?

Tags: overwatch

I enjoy saving my highlights, but I don't want them filling up the limited space on my C:\ drive, an SSD, especially when I have a nice big spinning drive for large documents.  I also don't want to manually move each file over after a gaming session either.  So how do I tell Overwatch where to save the highlights?  I've already looked through the main settings as well as the highlight saving settings and haven't seen anything that could be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This post on the Overwatch forums](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20757306266#post-1) has what you need, but to summarize:

1. Make sure Overwatch is closed.
2. Open your `Settings_v0.ini` file, located in `[user folder]\Documents\Overwatch\Settings`
3. Find the `[MovieExport.1]` section.
4. Add a line for `VideoPath = "<insert new path here>"` and provide a path. For example: `VideoPath = "C:\Users\yourusername\Desktop"`
5. Save and close the file.

In the future, it'll even display this path in the highlights screen.